# Unable to push newline to nodejs child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to run a command on my terraria server via nodejs

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const server = spawn(
  "dotnet",
  [
    "tModLoader.dll",
    "-server",
    "-config",
    "serverconfig.txt",
    "-port",
    "7771",
    "-noupnp",
    "-ip",
    "172.23.85.11",
    "-world",
    "C:\\Users\\cringe\\Documents\\My Games\\Terraria\\tModLoader-1.4.3\\Worlds\\world.wld",
    "-pass",
    "",
  ],
  {
    stdio: "pipe",
    cwd: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\tModLoader",
  }
);

server.on("error", (error) => console.log(error));
server.stdout.on("data", (data) => console.log(data.toString()));
server.stderr.on("data", (data) => console.log(data.toString()));
server.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  if (data.toString().includes("exit")) {
    console.log("exiting server");
    server.stdin.write("exit\r\n", (error) => {
      if (error) console.log(error);
    });
  }
});
```

The issue is that a newline is not triggering and the command doesn't execute.

I tried the following:

- Calling `stdin.write("exit\n")` and `stdin.write("exit\r\n")`

```
server.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  if (data.toString().includes("exit")) {
    console.log("exiting server");
    server.stdin.write("exit\r\n", (error) => {
      if (error) console.log(error);
    });
  }
});
```

Nothing happened.

- Calling `stdin.cork()` and `stdin.uncork()` for `stdin.wirte("exit\r\n")`

```
server.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  if (data.toString().includes("exit")) {
    console.log("exiting server");
    
    server.stdin.cork();
    server.stdin.write("exit\r\n", (error) => {
      if (error) console.log(error);
    });
    server.stdin.uncork();
  }
});
```

Nothing happened.

- Calling `stdin.end("exit")`

```
server.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  if (data.toString().includes("exit")) {
    console.log("exiting server");
    server.stdin.end("exit");
  }
});
```

The command was pushed through, but the server said that it's invalid, even though it absolutely is. My guess is that `stdin.end()` pushed something else in and corrupted the command somehow.

Comment: If I've understood the question (you want to stop the server) — this is what the [`subprocess.kill`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal) API addresses.

Comment: This works but the game data isn't saved, calling kill forcefully stops the server. I need stop it via the exit command so that the server properly saves everything and does any cleanup that it needs to do.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699810/unable-to-push-newline-to-nodejs-child-process?noredirect=1#comment135223780_76699810) Understood. The server code should handle `SIGINT` and do those finalization tasks quickly before shutting down. If it doesn't, that's something that should be modified in the server code.

Comment: To my knowledge and testing the server does not handle any signals and modifying the server code of such a game is far beyond my expertiese.

Comment: It sounds like you might need information about the IPC behavior specifics regarding the server software. I think [this is the associated GitHub repo](https://github.com/tModLoader/tModLoader), which includes links to a Discord community, etc.